# Is a visa in advance required for 7-day tourist stay in UAE for Chinese citizens?

Tags: visas, china, uae, chinese-citizens

First of all, I've read [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81602/11668), but it seems to conflict with other information on the web.

On [the London UAE embassy website](https://www.mofa.gov.ae/EN/DiplomaticMissions/Embassies/London/Services/Pages/Visa.aspx) and [the Emirates website](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visas/) it says that PRC passport holders can get visa on arrival. There are also [other websites](https://www.visitdubai.com/en/travel-planning/travel-tools/visa-and-entry-information) suggesting the same.

However, the aforementioned question on this site suggests otherwise, and so does [VisaHQ](https://www.visahq.co.uk/united-arab-emirates/requirements/china/resident-united-kingdom/). Are they merely out of date? I see that it seems that the UAE visa situation for Chinese citizens changed in 2016, according to [this article](https://www.thenational.ae/uae/uae-eases-visas-for-chinese-visitors-1.197449).

It looks likely that a visa is not needed, but with so much conflicting information, I'm not sure. Is the embassy website authoritative in such matters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chinese nationals **do not require** advance visa arrangements for a short visit to UAE.

> **Visa Exemptions:**
>
> Nationals of China (People’s Rep.) with a normal passport for a maximum stay of 30 days.
>
> Nationals of China (People’s Rep.) with a "Passport for Public Affairs" for a maximum stay of 30 days.

Source: [Timatic via Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=CN&NV=China&DC=AE&DV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=6163fef68f8ef8e5ec9e7c25bd8c04d42ece9d5)

Then, [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visas/) itself also says this

> **Visas on arrival**
>
> (A) If you are a passport holder of the below country or territory, no advance visa arrangements are required to visit the UAE. Simply disembark your flight at Dubai International Airport and proceed to Immigration, where your passport will be stamped with a 30-days visit visa free of charge.
>
> ...
>
> People's Republic of China
>
> ...

Comment: Thanks! However, the Emirates website is already listed in my original post. In general the issue here is about how to tell what's authoritative, since there's so much conflicting information. While Emirates is directly tied to the Dubai government, I'm not sure their website is authoritative.

Comment: Timatic is more authoritative than an old post on SE, don't worry. The post that you link to, is 2 years old.

Comment: Ah! I see, I wasn't aware of what Timatic was. That certainly looks authoritative. Thanks! I'll also make a note on the other question.

Comment: A good read on that: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/27813/23117